# Nginx reverse proxying websockets

Tags: apache, node.js, nginx, fastcgi

Is there a way to compile nginx to handle reverse proxying websockets requests? I'm building a realtime app in Node.JS and need a web server on top of this. Everything I've read says Nginx cannot reverse proxy websockets requests, so I'm a little confused on how I should approach this problem.

I was thinking about just implementing all server logic in Node, but there are some problems with this approach

1) PHP - I need a way to serve PHP files
2) Static files - I really like that nginx is very fast for static files. There are some modules for this, though, so this problem isn't too big.
3) When I need to update my Node app, I would like to be able to restart that part separately from the main server. Also, if the Node app crashes for some reason, I don't want the whole web server to go down!

Comment: Just use a node.js load balancer and have a node & nginx server behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to setup virtual hosts in nginx for multiple subdomains and run each service on a separate one. That way you don't have to worry about distinguishing websockets requests from standard http requests on the same port.

Also, you can run php behind nginx using PHP-FPM but that's quite a challenge to get working, and for that reason Apache may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something similar, here is the nginx server config( file: MY_DOMAIN.tk.conf on: /etc/nginx/config.d/) that work for me, with:

- let's encrypt tls cert for ssl
- php7.2 reverse proxy
- nodejs reverse proxy for websockets server running on port 8000.

  ```
  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default upgrade;
      '' close;
  }

  upstream appserver {
      server localhost:8000; # appserver_ip:ws_port
  }

  server {

      server_name MY_DOMAIN.tk;

      root /var/www/html;
      index index.php;

      location /ws {
          proxy_pass http://appserver;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
      }

      location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
      }

      location ~ \.php$ {
          include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
          fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
      }


      client_max_body_size 128m;
      # add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000" always;

      listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN.tk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_DOMAIN.tk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
      include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  }

  server {
      if ($host = MY_DOMAIN.tk) {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      } # managed by Certbot

      server_name MY_DOMAIN.tk;
      listen 80;
      return 404; # managed by Certbot

  }
  ```

by doing this then you can conect to wss://MY_DOMAIN.tk/ws